# Cube is already deployed, need to update friendly names in DSV, how to push those updates into the cube?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssas

So, as the title reads I need to update the friendly names of attributes and measures in the datasourceview (DSV).  I have done so which is fairly straightforward.  The problem I am now running into is getting these changes into the cube.  I have tried deploying the cube, processing the dimensions, processing the cube.  (I have tried all of these in numerous sequences)

I would think that this would be something that happens a lot.  I can't believe that one would have to create a new cube each time friendly names are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I completely overlooked this you deploy/process your cube.  Then you have to go into the tab cube structure.  Delete your old measure or attribute and add the newly named one in its place.  If you have a better way of doing this please let me know.